# How to print result of function "add" from class "Add" from "Fun with Type Functions"

Tags: haskell, typeclass, type-families

Below the code from here [Fun with Type Functions](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Simonpj/Talk%3aFunWithTypeFuns)

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances, FlexibleContexts, TypeFamilies #-}

-- Start basic
class Add a b where
  type SumTy a b
  add :: a -> b -> SumTy a b

instance Add Integer Double where
  type SumTy Integer Double = Double
  add x y = fromIntegral x + y

instance Add Double Integer where
  type SumTy Double Integer = Double
  add x y = x + fromIntegral y

instance (Num a) => Add a a where
  type SumTy a a = a
  add x y = x + y
-- End basic
```

This is the code which I'm trying to run:

```
main = print $ show (add 1 1)
```

This is the result:

```
No instance for (Show (SumTy a0 b0))
      arising from a use of `show'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Show (SumTy a0 b0))
    In the second argument of `($)', namely `show (add 1 1)'
    In the expression: print $ show (add 1 1)
    In an equation for `main': main = print $ show (add 1 1)
```

I've tried few things like putting "data" everywhere:

Result 1

```
Not a data constructor: `a'
```

Result 2 (after removing "instance (Num a)")

```
Multiple declarations of `Double'
Declared at: ...
```

like adding some function:

```
class Add a b where
    type SumTy a b
    add :: a -> b -> SumTy a b
    s :: SumTy a b -> String

instance Add Integer Double where
    type SumTy Integer Double = Double
    add x y = fromIntegral x + y
    s (SumTy _ x) = show x

main = print $ show (s (add 1 2.0) )
```

with this result:

```
Not in scope: data constructor `SumTy'
```

As you may have noticed I'm stuck so any help is priceless for me. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that there is not enough context to determine which instance of `Add` to use, and hence the type of the result cannot be determined. Since ghc doesn't know which types to use, it reports the most generic problem, there's no `Show` instance for a generic `SumTy a b`:

```
No instance for (Show (SumTy a0 b0))
      arising from a use of `show'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Show (SumTy a0 b0))
    In the second argument of `($)', namely `show (add 1 1)'
    In the expression: print $ show (add 1 1)
    In an equation for `main': main = print $ show (add 1 1)
```

The suggested "Possible fix" isn't what is required here, though. What you need is to specify the types of the arguments to `add`, so that the instance to use can be determined, and thus the result type:

```
*TyFun> show (add (1 :: Int) (1 :: Int))
"2"
*TyFun> show (add (1 :: Integer) (1 :: Integer))
"2"
*TyFun> show (add (1 :: Integer) (1 :: Double))
"2.0"
*TyFun> show (add (1 :: Integer) (1 :: Float))

<interactive>:7:1:
    No instance for (Show (SumTy Integer Float))
      arising from a use of `show'
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for (Show (SumTy Integer Float))
    In the expression: show (add (1 :: Integer) (1 :: Float))
    In an equation for `it':
        it = show (add (1 :: Integer) (1 :: Float))

<interactive>:7:7:
    No instance for (Add Integer Float) arising from a use of `add'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Add Integer Float)
    In the first argument of `show', namely
      `(add (1 :: Integer) (1 :: Float))'
    In the expression: show (add (1 :: Integer) (1 :: Float))
    In an equation for `it':
        it = show (add (1 :: Integer) (1 :: Float))
```

Comment: Excellent answer. Thank you very much. Maybe you could help me with writing this "s" function (from my code above) also? I do not understand how to write signature of "s". Is it possible at all?

Comment: @panurg, in your instance declaration you are pattern matching against `SumTy`, which is not correct: `SumTy` is only type alias, not data constructor (that's what the compiler is saying to you). You defined `SumTy` in your instance to be equal to `Double`, so everywhere in that instance usage of type `SumTy Integer Double` is equivalent to plain `Double`. Just substitute your `(SumTy _ x)` with just `x` and it will work.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev I don't know how to use "s" which you described in your post. I was trying: `s (2.0::Double)` and I got this:  
**Couldn't match type `SumTy a0 b0' with `Double'
In the first argument of `s', namely `(2.0 :: Double)'**

Could you explain me how should I use it?

Comment: @panurg, I guess you're right. I was sure this would work, but I tried to run it and got precisely yours error. I don't know why is this happening, maybe someone more knowing will answer.

Comment: @panurg I thought you tried to add `s` just as a crutch since you had problems calling `add` and printing the result. With an associated type synonym `type SumTy a b`, you can't use it, since there is no way to determine the types `a` and `b` from `SumTy a b`, different pairs of types could map to the same `SumTy` (they already do, `Integer` and `Double` in both orders map to `Double`), so the compiler can't know which instance to use.

Comment: @DanielFischer, It was exactly what I wanted that's why I said "Excellent answer" and that's why I marked your answer as accepted. But I'm learning haskell so I was curious if I understand good that it is impossible to write function "s". I didn't want to duplicate question about difference between data and type in type families so I asked about that in entry comment. Did I something wrong? By the way, thank you for your answer about "s".

Comment: @panurg No, you did nothing wrong. Asking for further clarifications in comments is perfectly fine (as long as it's still about the original question, and sometimes even if not). I originally ignored the `s` function because I thought it was an attempted crutch that is doomed do fail (you could have a workable version of `s` if `SumTy` were an associated data family, but that would make `add` far more awkward) and not something you were really interested in, sorry.